# N-dimensional vector rotation

Tags: java, vector, quaternions

I am working on a single class to handle vectors of any dimensions and type (float/int/double). Everything is completed except for rotation class.
It was easy to do with 3-dimensional vectors, but it seems impossible with this.
Does extending vectors past 3-dimensional space also require me to extend quaternions?

Anyway, my code looked like this before:

```
public Vector3f rotate(@NotNull Quaternion rotation){
    Quaternion conjugate = rotation.conjugated();
    Quaternion w = rotation.mul(this).mul(conjugate);
    return new Vector<N>(w.getX(), w.getY(), w.getZ());
}
```

Can someone please help me, I've been at this for quite some time now. Thank you!

Comment: Quaternions are specific to 3 dimensional rotations, they will not help you for arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: See the Aguilera-Perez Algorithm at http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2004/Papers_2004_Short/N29.pdf for a way to do it.